# Can't change brightness

Tags: display

I tryed ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10, but I can't change the brightness. It is always on maximum.

Comment: I try changing the xbacklight, max_brightness, íntall driver NVIDIA quadro...

Comment: If it is always at maximum, it is clearly driver issues. Please try my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1254557/903123 if you have Nvidia Driver.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a program called `xbacklight` , open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Brightness range can go upto 100 from 0 .
type this `xbacklight -set 50` to set brightness to 50 from 100.

you can also increase and decrease the brightness from present value to specified level if you want to increase to 10% from current value of brightness then you can give this

```
xbacklight -inc 10
```

and to decrease 10% you can give this

```
xbacklight -dec 10
```

Comment: I've tried but nothing changed

Comment: What you did exactly ? What's the output ? any error messages ?

Comment: No error messages, but brightness no change  !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change grub configuration file. Open it

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and go to the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Now, next step depend on your computer. Try to change the above line, with one of the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor”

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=legacy”

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux”

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi_osi=”
```

Every time that you edit `/eft/default/grub` file you have to run the following command that will apply changes.

```
sudo update-grub
```

To see results you have to reboot your system.

If the previous solution doesn't change your situation, you can try to do 2 things:

- update your kernel
- use a workaround

**Update your kernel to latest Ubuntu version**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

**Workaround**

Make a script to increment your brightness and one to decrement and bind them to a shortcut. You can try to use mine that I'm using on my PC.

Brighness up:

```
#! /bin/bash

# get max brightness and actual brighness
MAX=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`
AC_BR=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

# grow brightness of 5%
AC_BR=$((MAX / 100 * 5 + AC_BR))

# check if i can set new brightness
if (($AC_BR <= $MAX)); then
  echo $AC_BR > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
fi
```

Brightness down:

```
#! /bin/bash

# get max brightness and actual brighness
MAX=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`
AC_BR=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

# decrease brightness of 5%
AC_BR=$((AC_BR - MAX / 100 * 5))

# check if i can set new brightness
if (($AC_BR > 0)); then
  echo $AC_BR > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
else
  echo 5
fi
```

Copy the two bash scripts in two different file and give them execution permission:

```
chmod +x <file_name>
```

Move two script into your local bin directory to let you access to them everywhere in terminal:

```
sudo mv <file_brightness_up> <file_brightness_down> /usr/local/bin
```

Now you are ready to bind the scripts with shortcut. From *System Setting* select *Keyboard* and then *Shortcuts*. Select from the list on the left *Custom Shortcuts* and press *Add shortcut* button (+). Insert something as *name* and `<file_brightness_up>` file name as *command* and save.
Then double click on right column and press your preferred shortcut.

Do the same for brightness down script.

To be sure that script works you have to change brightness file owner. So open `/etc/rc.local` file

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and add the following line before `exit 0`:

```
chown <username>:<username> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Where  is your user name. Reboot your system to apply changes.

It should work because also your PC have an Intel graphic card. So you should get actual brightness value with:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: In file  /sys/class/  have only acpi_video0 and nv_backlight, don't have intel_backlight !